# Why is running Linux on android via UserLAnd less performant?

Tags: linux, android, container

Now that `LinuxOnDex` has been discontinued by Samsung a lot of people use `UserLAnd` to run Linux on their android phones instead.

On the web i read a lot that running linux via `UserLAnd` is [not very performant](https://forum.xda-developers.com/t/guide-review-installing-linux-using-userland-on-dex.3912266/). But i can't find any webpage that explains why this is so. Is it because Linux uses the phones hardware (CPU/RAM) less efficiently when it is run from inside a container? Or is the performance affected in some other way? I would also like to know by how much performance is affected. Does running linux inside the `UserLAnd` container only marginally affect the performance or does it affect it by a great amount?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with any emulator, UserLAnd still has to go through the host operating system, Android, which uses system resources. Direct passthrough (which would speed up emulation) isn't possible since UserLand doesn't leverage root privileges, so any computation has to be done through the API Android opens. More detail can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OS_virtualization_and_emulation_on_Android). To succinctly answer your question: the process of emulating Linux on Android uses RAM and CPU due to the inherent latency in passing commands through a "host" operating system.

As for your second question, based on complaints on the [github page](https://github.com/CypherpunkArmory/UserLAnd/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+slow+) and some cursory searches around the internet, UserLAnd doesn't appear to slow down the system by a lot, though the amount of noticeable slowdown experienced is dependent on your phone's hardware (amount of RAM specifically will have a large impact, and to a lesser extent CPU power).